# FFMPEG create image sequence of equal length to original video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-encoding

I am trying to convert a video to an image sequence for importing into my video editor. First I check the frame rate with:

```
ffprobe -v 0 -of compact=p=0 -select_streams 0 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate Forest.mp4
```

which returns

```
r_frame_rate=30/1
```

The original video is 1 minute 12 seconds...

when I run

```
ffmpeg -i Forest.mp4 -r 30 forest/image-%03d.dpx
```

it gives back this:

```
ffmpeg version 2.7.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC) 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-shared --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-postproc --enable-avfilter --enable-pthreads --enable-x11grab --enable-vdpau --disable-avisynth --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnut --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --disable-stripping
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Forest.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
  Duration: 00:01:00.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1277 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1144 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, image2, to 'forest/image-%03d.dpx':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: dpx, rgb24, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.41.100 dpx
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> dpx (native))
```

and creates only about one second of video.

I'd like it to match the source, so that when I pull the audio and import it into my editing software I'm trying to learn they will match up.

Comment: Just realized you [crossposted this to Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42310342/1109017) and it got answered there as well. Crossposting is discouraged: it wastes time, so two of us spent time providing similar answers to the same question. Also, it was offtopic at SO because that's for programming questions only.

Comment: @llogan who says it's discouraged? Where is it in the terms of service? If it's not then it's your opinion, why should we listen to your opinion?

Comment: @bluejayke See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: @illogan not sure what that proves, there's one accepted answer that says no without giving a source in the terms of service , while many other answers and comments disagree. The one who posted that question isn't a moderator, he could have chosen any question as the accepted answer. Does anyone who posts on the meta stack exchange have the right to decide the rule by picking an accepted answer? Rules are defined only in the terms of service, without a written rule from there there is only opinions

Comment: @bluejayke I can't answer on behalf of Stack Exchange: feel free to ask your Q on meta. But I can tell you why I think crossposting is bad. There are many more people asking ffmpeg Qs here than there are users answering. The majority of answers are provided by a few users. We (eventually) see most of the Qs regardless of location. I only have a certain amount of time each day to answer. Sometimes I answer a crosspost without yet noticing the other has already been answered. Otherwise I would have helped another user instead. I then run out of time to help others, leaving unanswered Qs.

Comment: @illogqn but why should you scrutinize people on something that yo think is bad, if it's not in the terms of use? Did people signing up to this site do so Ruth the expectations that they should have to listen to whatever other users feel is bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're outputting individual images there is no need to use `-r`. Individual frames have no duration, so duration is meaningless.

All you have to run is:

```
ffmpeg -i Forest.mp4 forest/image-%03d.dpx
```